# how to apply javascript function to multiple textboxes with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form where a user needs to input time entries for a date range.  I need to validate what they're inputting so I was hoping I could create one function to simply validate a value to make sure it's numeric.  Then tie that function to each textbox that has a css class of hourmin.  I think I'm headed in the right direction below but I'm not sure how to finish it.

```
$(".hourmin").change(function () {
    //apply this validation call to the textbox which has .hourmin class
});
```

Comment: well, are you looking for `$(this).method()` ?

Comment: This looks correct.  Where are you having a problem?

Comment: What issue are you exactly facing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a css class `invalid` to highlight the invalid field, then use something akin to this:

```
$(".hourmin").change(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('invalid', validate($(this).val()));
});
```

where `validate()` does your validation and returns a boolean. Have a look at [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric) for a possible implementation of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(this) to get the current textbox as a jQuery object and [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method for getting its value.

Answer (score 0):

See [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)
For a long discussion on how to determine if a value is numeric. To get the value:

```
$(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
Date:<input type="text" id="day" size="10" class="date" /> <input type="text" id="month" size="10" class="date" /> <input type="text" id="year" size="10" class="date"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.date').change(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    var val = $(this).val();
    switch(id)
    {
        case "day":
            //validate day
            break;
        case "month":
            //validate month
            break;
        case "year":
            //validate year
            break;
    }
});
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it was the $(this) that I was missing.  Here's the final code in case it helps anyone else.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".hourmin").change(function () {
            numbers = $(this).val();
            $(this).val(numbers.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ''));
        });
    });
```